# Heroku - Firewall necessary?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, heroku, firewall

I'm currently considering Heroku as a new hosting platform. So far I've been working with various services on Amazon AWS so I'm still trying to figure out some pieces, especially when it comes to security.

I'm used to setting up a firewall & restricting the access. E.g. should only the application have access to the database as well as certain IP ranges. In Heroku there is no such setup possible, I can't configure a firewall.

With Heroku Private Spaces, I can whitelist IP addresses for my apps but that's not really satisfying.

Is it not necessary with a PaaS to configure a firewall to make sure the DB is not externally accessible for example? Additionally, my test and staging environment shouldn't be publicly accessible either (for security reasons).

I would appreciate your thoughts on this.